# How to remove background color in Pygame (make_surface)?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I have used opencv to read png files (with no background) and convert them into pygame surface. Here are the two examples of how I did it:

Method 1:

```
character=pygame.image.load("character.png")
```

Method 2:

```
CharacterImage=cv2.imread("character.png")
CharacterImage=convertToRGB(CharacterImage,CharSize,CharSize)
#charSize is desired character size (for example: 50)
#I have created a user defined function as pygame renders in RGB whereas cv2 renders in BGR image format.
CharacterActions.append(rotate(pygame.surfarray.make_surface(CharacterImage),charrot))
#charrot is rotation angle
```

I understand that I could manually resize images and then use the first method to get the transparent background image. But I want to understand if its possible to obtain the same via second method? I don't want to manually edit so many images resizing them and that's why I want to know if there's a way for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the problem with using the `pygame.transform` module?

Comment: Thanks this worked! Didn't know about this property before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the images you load using your Method 1 (`pygame.image.load()`), you should use [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) and [`pygame.transform.rotate()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) to manipulate the loaded image.
To maintain the transparency, you need to keep the alpa of the image you are loading. To do that you need to use [.convert_alpha()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) on the resulting image. You can do that after or before the transform.

For each of these commands I have linked them to the documentation, just click on them so you can read it.

Comment: .convert_alpha didn't work to make the background transparent. However your first solution of transform.scale worked! Thanks.

Comment: If your loaded image already has a transparent background then convert_alpha() should maintain it. If it is not actually transparent but has a set color that should be ignored/considered transparent then you need to use pygame.Surface.set_colorkey